# Best way to communicate server-generated map to client

Tags: lance

I am starting out with lance-gg and am building a game in which a new game map is generated every few minutes. The client game engine needs to receive the generated map. Currently I am registering the map as a serializable object and adding a new instance to the game world when the server starts.

```
class Map extends serialize.DynamicObject {
    constructor(id, width, height) {
        super(id);
        this.class = Map;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.netScheme = {
            tiles: { type: "CLASSINSTANCE" },
        };
    }
    randomTiles() {
        const tiles = [];
        _.forEach(_.range(this.width), (x) => {
            tiles[x] = [];
            _.forEach(_.range(this.height), (y) => {
                tiles[x][y] = _.random(0, 1);
            });
        });
        return tiles;
    }
}
```

The map is a double array of integers and might be quite large so I'd like to avoid implementing it as part of a netscheme (which I dont think I'm doing correctly here anyway) as it doesn't need to be updated very often. I would also like to keep a reference to it in the game world to keep it separate from objects that actually change position.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lance will only broadcast game objects if their netscheme'd data has changed.  Lance will also broadcast all of the game objects when a new user has connected.

In your case, this means that if the map only changes every few minutes, then you should be fine leaving it as a game object, and relying on Lance to detect changes and broadcast when necessary.

An alternative approach is to emit the Map data directly to users using `socket.emit` approach as described in this stack overflow question: [Sending "secret" data to individual players in Lance Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352173/sending-secret-data-to-individual-players-in-lance-game).